# Unresolved attribute reference

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Почему при наведении на элемент `objects` выдает такой warning(сам код работает)? Из-за этого не работает intellisense. Использую pycharm.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Tournament_Summary


def index(request):
    test = Tournament_Summary.objects.all()[:50]

    return render(request, "index.html", {'test': test})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django.
```

Ставьте галочку напротив **Enable django support**.

Этого уже будет достаточно для `objects`. Для более полной интеграции(переход по вьюхам через название ссылок и т.д.):

**Django Project Root** -> папка, в которой лежит `manage.py`.

**Settings** -> файл с настройками(дефолт: `settings.py`).

Сохраняемся. Ждем пока обновится индекс.

Comment: я так понял это актуально только для платной версии, в Community Edition не работает.

Comment: да. К сожалению в комьюнити версии нет поддержки Django. Если вы являетесь студентом,вы можете без проблем получить professional edition бесплатно на период обучения